# Проблема с освобождением памяти в деструктор c++

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Пишу свой класс математических матриц, храню все в `double**`. Все работало нормально, пока не решил заняться деструктором. Теперь при вызове какого либо оператора или функции мне вылетает исключение: "Ошибка доступа к чтению". Я уже понял из-за чего она вылетает. 
Вот мой типичный код:

```
Matrix Matrix::operator+ (Matrix M)
{
    Matrix Temp(Rows, Columns);
    for (unsigned i(0); i < Rows; i++)
        for (unsigned j(0); j < Columns; j++)
            Temp[i][j] = M[i][j] + Element[i][j];
    return Temp;
}
```

Когда он возвращает `Temp`, он уничтожает все элементы, и `Temp` не доходит до конца.
Вот деструктор:

```
Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    for (unsigned i(0); i < Rows; i++)
        delete[] Element[i];
    delete[] Element;
}
```

Подскажите как мне правильно сделать деструктор.

Comment: А оператор присваивания и конструктор копирования вы написали? Нострадамлю :), что нет, а генерируемые компилятором выполняют простое поверхностное копирование указателя... А деструктор - если вы выделяете память аналогично - правильный и в полной мере ни при чем.

Comment: К предыдущему комментарию стоит добавить про необходимость определить __перемещающий конструктор и перемещающее присваивание__, ибо [правило пяти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B)#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8). Копирование там, где этого можно избежать - грех.

Comment: Передавать аргумент нужно по ссылке : `Matrix::operator+ (Matrix const & M)` так быстрее. Покажите все конструкторы, не вижу как вы выделяете память.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, я конструктор копирования не сделал

Comment: @AlexGlebe С вопросом все решено, спасибо за совет по поводу передачи по сслыки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы забыли реализовать правильный конструктор копирования, так как конструктор копирования по умолчанию просто копирует указатели. И когда у вас будет два объекта, которые ссылаются на одну и ту же область памяти и у них обоих вызовется деструктор, то он попытается дважды освободить одну и ту же память.

Пример кода по правилу [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom):

```
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(size_t rows = 0, size_t columns = 0) 
        : rows_(rows), columns_(columns),
          pMat(rows || columns ? new double[rows * columns] : nullptr) 
    {}
    Matrix(Matrix const & obj) 
        : rows_(obj.rows_), columns_(obj.columns_),
          pMat(obj.rows_ || obj.columns_ ? 
              new double[obj.rows_ * obj.columns_] : nullptr)
    {
        std::copy(obj.pMat, obj.pMat + obj.rows_ * obj.columns_, pMat);
    }
    Matrix(Matrix&& obj) noexcept
        : Matrix()
    {
        swap(*this, obj);
    }
    ~Matrix() {
        delete[] pMat;
    }

    friend void swap(Matrix& first, Matrix& second) {
        using std::swap;

        swap(first.rows_, second.rows_);
        swap(first.columns_, second.columns_);
        swap(first.pMat, second.pMat);
    }

    Matrix const & operator= (Matrix obj) {
        swap(*this, obj);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    size_t rows_;
    size_t columns_;
    double * pMat;
};
```